# Could you please tell me what these characters are?

Tags: mandarin

I can't decipher this pic. Will someone please kindly tell me what they are? It is from the name of a language school. Looks a bit like 拍扙, whatever that is.

[image: From the name of a language school]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

柏林
Berlin (the capital of Germany)

---

快速提升中文程度的方法：
1. 初級者多看中文文章。
2. 中級者多寫中文文章。
3. 高級者多用中文思考。
所以，除了初學者可能有困難外，建議大家多用中文問答。

Comment: 我也觉得有不少难度较高的问题，用中文问答更合适一些。